# What is "plain one to one cable"?

Tags: cable

1. What is "plain one to one cable" in the following quote from
   [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Direct-attached_storage#Storage_features_common_to_SAN.2C_DAS_and_NAS):

   > A DAS device can be shared between multiple computers, as long as it
   >   provides multiple interfaces (ports) that allow concurrent and direct
   >   access. This way it can be used in computer clusters. In fact, most
   >   SAN-attachable storage devices or NAS devices can be easily used as
   >   DAS devices – all that is needed is to disconnect their ports from the
   >   data network and connect one or more ports directly to a computer
   >   (with a **plain one-to-one cable**).
2. Is "plain one to one cable" able to connect two computers directly
   for communication between them?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

1. By 'plain one-to-one' I believe they are just saying one interface on a device connects to one interface on the other device through that cable opposed to connecting to more than one interface on either side of the cable.
2. I don't think a "plain one to one cable" is a specific type of cable. Therefore, yes there are cables that can connect two computers directly for communication (ethernet).

Answer (score 1):

The transport types listed on the Wikipedia page are for the most part "local" storage transport protocols.  ATA, SATA, eSATA, SCSI and SAS are all "point to point" protocols meaning they go from a host to a storage device.  The oldest standard there, ATA, did permit multiple devices on a single cable but that is only found in legacy machines now (>8 years old).  The one exception, Fibre Channel is a routable protocol that can go over FC switches but that's a feature for data centers, not consumers.

The "one to one" cable mentioned is just a cable for the transport protocol your DAS uses.  If you have an eSATA port on your DAS, then that's the kind of cable you'll need to use to attach it to your computer.  Some of those protocols require adapters in your computer to use.